# Will pexpect.spawn automatically run processes using multicores?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pexpect

I want to use python to write some script that runs parallel processes.

I learned that `pexpect.spawn`, `multiprocessing.Process` and `concurrent.futures` can all be used for parallel processing. I'm currently using `pexpect.spawn`, but I'm not sure whether `pexpect.spawn` will automatically utilize all the cores available.

This what `top` command returned when I used `pexpect.spawn` to start several workers. [image: the_image] Are those processes run on different cores? How can I read that? Why the number of processes returned by `top` is much larger than the number of cores of my computer?

Comment: It's better to use `htop`. It shows you the status of all the cores visually.

Comment: @Milo Lu I have tried `htop` on both Mac and Linux, but  I received an error `bash: htop: command not found...`

Comment: It has to be installed first. If you use ubuntu, `sudo apt-get install htop`